# Python .NET create an EndpointAddress

Tags: .net, python-3.x, endpoint

Trying to create an endpoint but getting an error when running the last line.

```
    identity = System.ServiceModel.EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("localhost")
    address1 = System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("svc1", "http://localhost:8000/Service",1)
    address2 = System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("svc2", "http://localhost:8000/Service",2)
    addressArray = [address1, address2]
    addresses = System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressHeaderCollection(addressArray)
    endpoint = System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(uri,identity,addresses)
```

Error is:
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

When I do addresses.Items I get []

How can I add the adressheaders to the collection correctly so that the endpointaddress creation can work?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get on track.  I'm guessing; it's not my area of expertise.

```
addressHeader1 = 
    AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("svc1","http://localhost:8000/service", 1);
addressHeader2 = 
    AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("svc2","http://localhost:8000/service", 2);

addressHeaders = new AddressHeader[2] { addressHeader1, addressHeader2 };

headers = new AddressHeaderCollection(addressHeaders);      

endpointIdentity = 
    EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(
   new Uri("http://localhost:8003/servicemodelsamples/service/incode/identity"),
   endpointIdentity, addressHeaders);

headerCollection = endpointAddress.Headers;
```